# Checking antipode on Enveloping algebra of a Lie Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups

Let $U\left(\mathfrak{g}\right)$ be the enveloping algebra of $\mathfrak{g}$.Let's define comultiplication, counit and antipode as
$$\triangle\left(X\right) =X\otimes1+1\otimes X,$$
$$\epsilon\left(X\right) =0,$$
$$S\left(X\right) =-X.$$
We can read everywhere that $U\left(\mathfrak{g}\right)$ with those applications is an hopf algebra. I'm checking the antipode condition and I find
$$
\mu\circ\left(S\otimes id\right)\circ\triangle\left(X\right)=$$
$$=\mu\circ\left(S\otimes id\right)\left(X\otimes1+1\otimes X\right)=$$
$$=\mu\circ\left(-X\otimes1+-1\otimes X\right)=$$
$$=-X-X=-2X$$
While it should be zero... What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The extension of the antipode map to $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$ maps each scalar to itself. Therefore$$(S\otimes\operatorname{id})(X\otimes1+1\otimes X)=-X\otimes1+1\otimes X$$and $\mu(-X\otimes1+1\otimes X)=0$.

Comment: I see thank you, can you give the two line that prove that the antipode maps each scalar to itself?

Comment: @Dac0 It's a matter of definition. The map $S\colon\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})\longrightarrow\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$ is the only anti-automorphism of $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$ such that $(\forall X\in\mathfrak{g}):s(X)=-X$. This means that $(\forall \lambda\in\mathbb{K}):S(\lambda)=\lambda$ and that$$S(X_1\ldots X_n)=(-X_n)\ldots(-X_1)=(-1)^nX_n\ldots X_1.$$

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!